# PigUnit not working for pig scripts that use HCatLoader

Tags: apache-pig, hcatalog

I have my pig script where I am loading like:

```
LOAD_A = LOAD '$DB_AND_TABLE' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
```

I'm overriding the alias in my pigunit as:

```
overrideInputAlias("LOAD_A", load_a);
```

Ideally, I think if I override the alias, pigunit should not try loading using HCatLoader, but it is complaining

```
ERROR 1000: Error during
parsing. Could not resolve org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader using imports: [,
java.lang., org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]
```

Could somebody please point me if I need to do something different with using `HCatLoader` with `PigUnit`?

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use `override()`.

```
test.override("LOAD_A", "LOAD_A = LOAD 'abc' USING PigStorage(',');
```

If you still get the same error, I would suggest you to add `hcatalog-pig-adapter` to your maven dependencies.

Comment: Hi Fred, I can run the pig script all fine using -useHCatalog. But it is the pigunit that is giving me trouble. Do I still need to provide the jars even if I override the alias?

Comment: What do you mean by override the alias? -useHCatalog? I don't think that will work in the unit test. I think you have to add the jars. I recommend you to use a tool like maven or similar.

Comment: I meant, running the pig script works fine on the hadoop cluster using -useHCatalog. And yes, I am using maven. regarding overriding the alias, in pigunit you can do `overrideInputAlias("LOAD_A", load_a);` like I pointed out in my question above, and technically pig should just take the data in the string array of load_a and not even try to look up the HCatloader class

Comment: Looks like I  misunderstood  your question, I have edited my answer.